# How to register filters (formerly helpers) in Latte?

Tags: php, nette

I would like to create my own filter for [Latte templating engine](http://latte.nette.org/en/). There is an example in their documentation but it doesn't describe how to register it inside presenter.

```php
$latte = new Latte\Engine;
$latte->addFilter('myFilter', function ($s) {
    return someMagic($s)
});
```

I bet there will be simple way to get instance of Latte\Engine inside presenter but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Filters can be registered through `config.neon` too.

```
services:
    nette.latteFactory:
        setup:
            - addFilter(abs, @App\Latte\AbsFilter)

    - App\Latte\AbsFilter
```

Filter class can look like this:

```
namespace App\Latte;

class AbsFilter extends \Nette\Object
{
    /**
     * @param int $number
     * @return int
     */
    public function __invoke($number)
    {
        return abs($number);
    }
}
```

Comment: nice one! thank you. i didn't know about this option. marked as solution

Answer (score 4):

In presenter, there is instance of `Latte\Engine` available in `$this->template` so everything you have to do is register filter like this:

```
<?php
    abstract class BasePresenter extends Nette\Application\UI\Presenter
    {
        public function beforeRender()
        {
            // register filters
            $this->template->addFilter('myFilter', function ($s) {
                // don't forget to set your own magic
                return someMagic($s);
            });
        }

    }
?>
```

I postend an example using `BasePresenter` which is parent of all others presenters but you can register it only in presenter you want to and speed up your application.

Comment: Did you get any exception or something? Let me know and I'll help you. Also I will try it by myself tonight, maybe something has changed in Latte.

Comment: I wanted to disable default auto filters `escape` it was dispaying html code as code, so I found that there is `noescape` filter so it works now. thanks

Comment: Automatic escaping is important, don't avoid eacaping since you don't have to - like in case of listing articles from database or so.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Nortys answer.

Sometimes it's usefull to inject some data from Presenter into anonymous function:

```
<?php
abstract class BasePresenter extends Nette\Application\UI\Presenter
{
    public function beforeRender()
    {
        $locale = 'en';

        // register filters
        $this->template->addFilter('myFilter', function ($s) use ($locale) {
            // don't forget to set your own magic
            return someMagic($s, $locale);
        });
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Nette 3.0 / 2020 Approach with Dependency Injection

Registering filters in control or presenter can lead to forgotten registration of filter. **They should be registered once, at one place for whole application.**

This approach is easy for extension, 1 new filter = 1 new class, no configuration, no touching other code. Apart other answers here, this one respects open-closed solid principle.

### LatteFactory service with FilterProvider

First, we make a filter provide service:

```php
interface FilterProviderInterface
{
    public function getName(): string;
}
```

```php
final class PlusFilterProvider implements FilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __invoke(int $number, int $anotherNumber): int
    {
        return SomeStaticClass::plus($number, $anotherNumber);
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return 'plus';
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Latte;

use Latte\Engine;
use Latte\Runtime\FilterInfo;

final class LatteFactory
{
    /**
     * @var FilterProviderInterface[]
     */
    private array $filterProviders;

    /**
     * @param FilterProviderInterface[] $filterProviders
     */
    public function __construct(array $filterProviders)
    {
        $this->filterProviders = $filterProviders;
    } 

    public function create(): Engine
    {
        $engine = new Engine();

        // register your filters here
        foreach ($this->filterProviders as $filterProvider) {
            $engine->addFilter($filterProvider->getName(), $filterProvider);
        }

        return $engine;
    }
}
```

### How to add a new filter?

- create new class that implements your interface `FilterProviderInterface`
- register is as a service in your config, or better autodiscover it with [search extension](https://doc.nette.org/cs/3.0/configuring#toc-search)
- that's it :)

### Do you want to learn more?

I wrote more detail post [How to Get Rid of Magic, Static and Chaos from Latte Filters](https://tomasvotruba.com/blog/2020/08/17/how-to-get-rid-of-magic-static-and-chaos-from-latte-filters/) where I explain the pros and cons of alternatives and **why this one wins**.

Comment: Don't forget to change your neon config with new latteFactory

    - App\Latte\LatteFactory
    latte.latteFactory: @App\Latte\LatteFactory::create